# Trying to predict imdbRating of the movies on the basis of independent factors

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I am new to machine learning and have imdb movies dataset and trying to predict the 'imdbRating' of movies on the basis of factors :- `'ratingCount'`,`'nrOfWins'`,`'nrOfNominations'`,`'nrOfPhotos'`,  `'nrOfNewsArticles'`, `'nrOfUserReviews'`,`'nrOfGenre'`.

My simplest python code is [code-python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pb9b6.png).

I have used in my code 'Support Vector Regression' machine learning algorithm. I just want to know whether my approach as shown in the python code is correct and valid or not and if this approach is correct then,  can I use other regression algorithms like `RandomForestRegression`, `DecisionTreeRegression` for predicting the `'imdbRatings'` in the same simple code fashion or not.

If my approach is wrong then is it because I have more than one independent variables and I should be using only one independent variable in order to predict the 'imdbRating' which is my dependent variable.

```
X = df[['ratingCount', 'nrOfWins', 'nrOfNominations','nrOfPhotos','nrOfNewsArticles', 'nrOfUserReviews', 'nrOfGenre']][0:100].values
y = df['imdbRating'][0:100].values

from sklearn.svm import SVR

regressor  =  SVR()

regressor.fit(X, y)
regressor.predict([[40550, 1, 0, 19, 96.0, 85.0, 3.0]])
```

output: `array([ 8.3859375])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over your code and dataset, you need much much more data from IMDb in order to make this work. A support vector regression algorithm will not be able to interpret and predict based off of 6 examples. You might need hundreds of examples that have differing ratings, very differing. Good luck with your project!

Comment: What I have shown above in code is by taking only 100 dataset values but I have in actual dataset of 15000 rows/units

Comment: 15000 rows of data is a good amount to get this to work. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response and So I guess my fundamental approach is right in code.?

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct, it all depends on having the correct amount of data and correct type. Have fun with your project

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,Noah Meislik. Your suggestion was valuable for newbie like me who has just begun with machine learninga algos.